# Zero-or-one in backwards regex search

Tags: regular-expression

Given the document

```
a
^
a
```

(where `^` denotes the cursor position), the forward search `/a\?` succeeds, but the backward search `?a\?` fails.  Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented:

```
\?      Just like \=.  Cannot be used when searching backwards with the "?"
        command. {not in Vi}
```

Note that `\?` is "Just like \=", so you can

```
?a\=
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you!  I only read the line `/\?     \?      \?      0 or 1          as many as possible (*)` in the documentation for `/multi`; it didn't occur to me that I had to dive further into the documentation.  I had also wondered why there was a synonym available ….

Answer (score 5):

From [`:help /\?`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%3f):

```
\?      Just like \=.  Cannot be used when searching backwards with the "?"
        command. {not in Vi}
```

It's confusing behaviour, but the reason for this is that you can use the command with an offset to go `n` lines up or down after the match:

```
/a/1
?a?1
```

There is no easy way to disambiguate between regular `?`s and the `?` to separate the pattern from the offset. This is why `\?` behaves as a literal `?`, and not as the special atom you expect it to.

Comment: Thank you!  I have accepted [nobe4](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10858/2108)'s answer because it was slightly earlier, but I appreciate your explanation.  Do you know why escaping the `?` isn't enough to disambiguate?

Comment: @LSpice That's okay. [Fastest gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/166789) and all. Anyway, how would you escape `?`? There are *three* possible meanings of `?`: literal `?`, `\?`, and offset separator. *In principle* Vim could make a new atom for this (such as `\\?` or `\??`) but this would cause more compatibility problems and confusion than it solves, and since it's already identical to the existing `\=` I don't really see why this should be added.